# Creating a .dll using cygwin and gcc without specifying libraries

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, cygwin, shared-libraries

Consider I want to build a shared library from my C++ file `foo.cpp`. The file has dependencies on various libraries, e.g. a b c, i.e., `-la -lb -lc`. Under linux, I can do this for example with the following call:

```
g++ -shared -o foo.so foo.cpp
```

Note that I do not have to specify `-la -lb -lc` here. The linker simply ignores all unresolved symbols.

When I tried the same thing under windows in a cygwin environment, I got linker errors telling me that symbols from the libraries `a` `b` and `c` where not found. I had to add `-la -lb -lc` to the command:

```
g++ -shared -o foo.dll foo.cpp -la -lb -lc
```

This works, however, this slows down the process considerably, since the symbol tables of the libraries have to be read. How can I build a .dll with cygwin without having to specify the libraries I needs, i.e., how can I make the cygwin `g++` do the same thing the linux `g++` does.

Comment: This may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601949/building-a-shared-library-using-gcc-on-linux-and-mingw-on-windows