# Creating a shared library with an undefined reference on Cygwin

Tags: c, linker, cygwin

I'm porting what's primarily a very central (kind of like a libc extension) library from Linux to Cygwin and since I have a lot of setup and teardown and since I don't want to be using ctor/dtor attribute becaus of tcc compatibility, my library provides a `main` function and the user is supposed to be using a "my_main" function that gets called by the `main` function in the library.

It has worked very well on Linux but on Cygwin, I'm getting linker errors.

Here's an MCVE for building the library:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
cat > libmain.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
long my_main(int, char**);
int main(int C, char**V)
{

        int r = 0;
        puts("setup");
        if(0>my_main(C,V))
                r=-1;
        puts("teardown");
        return r;
}
EOF
gcc -shared -fpic -o libmain.so  libmain.c -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined
```

The above works on Linux, but on Cygwin, I'm getting:

```
/tmp/cc0s6qei.o:libmain.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `my_main'
/tmp/cc0s6qei.o:libmain.c:(.text+0x32): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `my_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can this be made to work on Cygwin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a shared library using gcc on Linux and MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601949/building-a-shared-library-using-gcc-on-linux-and-mingw-on-windows)

Comment: Are you, by chance, compiling from 64-bit Linux to 32-bit Cygwin, or vice-versa?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Nope. My main sys is 64 bit Linux and the Cygwin I'm trying to build my project on is 64 bit Win7 with Cygwin. I have tried compiling it on 32 bit Linuxes but haven't tried 32 bit Cygwin yet.

Comment: Try prefixing `extern` before `my_main`. So the prototype would look like: `extern long my_main(int, char**);`

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal That doesn't and shouldn't do anything. Extern on non-static non-inline function declarations doesn't do anything

Comment: you can't leave `my_main` undefined at link time, it does not work on any Windows platform Cygwin included

Comment: @matzeri I'm not very familiar with Windows. I'll read up on how its shared libraries work, but if you provide an executable recipe that fixes the example in the question before then, your answer might get upvoted and possibly accepted ;-).

Comment: Where is `my_main` defined ?

Comment: @matzeri In the main program (instead of main) that links the library.

Comment: easy way is to move it in the library.

Comment: @matzeri the whole point of this is that the user of library provides my_main.

Comment: see https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking for info on the matter of circular reference